# Закрепить элемент как фон

Tags: javascript

у меня есть js элемент "космическое пространство", мне нужно закрепить его так чтобы он был как задний фон на странице вебсайта, пробовал обернуть его и использовать css position: fixed;

с помощью чего я могу сделать желаемое?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  
  let camera
  let scene
  let renderer
  let material
  let mouseX = 0
  let mouseY = 0
  let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2
  let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2
  
  init()
  animate()
  
  function init () {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 5, 2000)
    camera.position.z = 500
  
    scene = new THREE.Scene()
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x0000ff, 0.001);

  
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
    const vertices = []
    const size = 2000
  
    for ( let i = 0; i < 20000; i ++ ) {
      const x = (Math.random() * size + Math.random() * size) / 2 - size / 2
      const y = (Math.random() * size + Math.random() * size) / 2 - size / 2
      const z = (Math.random() * size + Math.random() * size) / 2 - size / 2
  
      vertices.push(x, y, z)
    }
  
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3))
  
    material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      size: 1.5,
      color: 0xffffff,
    })
  
    const particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material)
    scene.add(particles)
  
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  
    document.body.style.touchAction = 'none';

    document.body.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove)
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize)
  }
  
  function onWindowResize () {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2
  
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  }
  
  function onPointerMove (event) {
    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX 
    mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY
  }
  
  function animate () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    render()
  }
  
  function render () {
    camera.position.x += (mouseX * 2 - camera.position.x) * 0.02
    camera.position.y += (-mouseY * 2 - camera.position.y) * 0.02
    camera.lookAt(scene.position)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    scene.rotation.x += 0.001
    scene.rotation.y += 0.002
  }
  
  </script>
```

Comment: Вот тут демонстрация https://codepen.io/ruslan-shaikhutdinov/pen/RwYgreY

Comment: _"пробовал обернуть его"_ Не вижу этой попытки.